# Not able to use "connect()" method to sign transactions with different account in HARDHAT

Tags: solidity, web3js, javascript, ethers.js, hardhat

I am making a smart contract so that I can send messages and other addresses can also send messages in that contract. So the **message**, **block.timestamp** and the **sender's address** will be stored in an "array of structs" in blockchain which will be done via transaction. Now in **scripts/deploy.js** file, we need **getSigners()** method so that we will be able to transact by "metamask" wallet. So, first check this line ---> `const [_, randomPerson,addr1, addr2] = await hre.ethers.getSigners()`.
We know that the 1st value in this array is the **owner** by default. So, "" _(underscore) "" is the owner in this case. So, firstly please check my "scripts/deploy.js" and "WavePortal.sol" file--->

**WavePortal.sol**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract WavePortal {

    uint256 totalWaves;

    event NewWave(address indexed from, uint timestamp, string message);

    struct Wave{
        address waver;
        string message;
        uint timestamp;
    }

    Wave[] waves;

    constructor() {
        console.log("Yo yo, I am a contract and I am smart");
    }


    function wave(string memory _message) public {
        totalWaves += 1;
        console.log("%s waved with message %s", msg.sender, _message);

        waves.push(Wave(msg.sender, _message, block.timestamp));

        emit NewWave(msg.sender, block.timestamp, _message);
    }

    function getAllWaves() public view returns (Wave[] memory){  //Array of waves
        return waves;
    }

    function getTotalWaves() public view returns (uint256) {
        console.log("We have %d total waves!", totalWaves);
        return totalWaves;
    }
}
```

**scripts/deploy.js**

```
const hre = require("hardhat");

const main = async () => {
  const waveContractFactory = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("WavePortal");
  const waveContract = await waveContractFactory.deploy();
  await waveContract.deployed();
  console.log("Contract address:", waveContract.address);

  let waveCount;
  waveCount = await waveContract.getTotalWaves();
  console.log(waveCount.toNumber());

  let waveTxn = await waveContract.wave("A message!");
  await waveTxn.wait();

  const [_, randomPerson, addr1, addr2] = await hre.ethers.getSigners();
  console.log("Address of _  is: ",_.address);   //Working absolutely fine
  console.log("Random Person: ", randomPerson);
  console.log("Address of Random Person is: ", randomPerson.address);

  waveTxn = await waveContract.connect(randomPerson).wave("Another message!");
  await waveTxn.wait();

  let allWaves = await waveContract.getAllWaves();
  console.log(allWaves);
  

  };

const runMain = async () => {
  try {
    await main();
    process.exit(0);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

runMain();
```

Now, when I am deploying it to localhost by running the command `npx hardhat node` after that I run this command in another terminal `npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network localhost`, Everything is working absolutely fine. I was getting the `address` of "_" as well as "randomPerson".

But when I was trying to deploy it by the command `npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network rinkeby`  via **Alchemy or Infura**, *(owner) is working totally fine, but other addresses like `randomPerson` or `addr1` or `addr2` is showing **undefined** when testing with console.log like `console.log("randomPerson is: ", randomPerson)` gives the output --> `undefined`.  So I am unable to use/call the functions of   **WavePortal.sol**   by randomPerson or addr1 or addr2 which we do via `connect()` method for other addresses.  I am only able to use/call its functions with "*(underscore)" which is the owner.   And so I am also unable to Deploy it on **Rinkeby** network of **Alchemy** or **Infura** via  `npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network rinkeby`.

I have tried each and everything but I am not getting the solution from anywhere.
My **hardhat.config.js** file is also properly updated as per Rinkeby or Ropsten whichever network I'm using.

So, Please help me regarding this.

Comment: What are the contents of your `hardhat.config.js`?  What do you have set as the `defaultNetwork`?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution to this question from Hardhat Website.

As we know that private keys are different for different Accounts, like I wanna use 2 or more Rinkeby Accounts in this case, so I need to include their **private keys** also in `hardhat.config.js` under accounts.

`accounts: [privateKey1, privateKey2, ...]`

Link --> `https://hardhat.org/config`